# Custom resolver to resolve model for /posts/create route

Tags: ember.js, routes

I am trying to use the resolver system to resolve a model for /posts/create.

My router mapping looks like:

```
this.resource('posts', function () {
    this.route('create', {
      path: '/create'
     });

    this.route('index', {
      path: '/:post_id'
    });
  });
```

When I go to the /posts/1234 route, my resolveModel method on the resolver is called, but when I go to /posts/create, it is not. I'm assuming that I'm missing a naming convention here, but I want to get /posts/create to use the resolver rather than creating a PostsCreateRoute just to have a one liner in the model hook.

Any help would be appreciated. I'd love to know if I'm approaching this incorrectly as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a jsbin with the rest of the code?

Comment: What do you mean by using the resolver?

Comment: @kingpin2k I'm using a custom resolver to find modules http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.DefaultResolver.html

Comment: @bantic Was going to whip up an example, but my question has been answered vvvv. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resolveModel` is being called in the first route because ember has a special convention for routes that include path params that use the convention `:model_id`. When ember sees this it will try to find an instance of the model with the id of the path param. You can see this behavior here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L871-L888.

The second route has no path params so ember's default behavior is to do nothing. If you want to create a new instance of the post model when a user enters that url you will need to declare your own model function to perform this action. For example:

```
App.PostCreateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('post', {});
  }
});
```